# Why doesn't an async function with two non-static references and a static reference compile?

Tags: rust, async-await, static, lifetime-scoping

An async function with one static reference compiles:

```
pub async fn test_0(_a: &'static str)  {
}
```

An async function with a non-static and a static reference compiles:

```
pub async fn test_1<'a>(_a: &'a str, _b: &'static str)  {
}
```

An async function with three non-static references compiles:

```
pub async fn test_2<'a, 'b, 'c>(_a: &'a str, _b: &'b str, _c: &'c str)  {
}
```

A function that takes two non-static references and a static reference and returns a future compiles:

```
pub fn test_3_desugared<'a, 'b>(_a: &'a str, _b: &'b str, _c: &'static str) -> impl std::future::Future<Output=()> {
  std::future::ready(())
}
```

So why does an async function that takes two non-static references and a static reference *not* compile?

```
pub async fn test_3<'a, 'b>(_a: &'a str, _b: &'b str, _c: &'static str)  {
}
```

The compilation error in question:

```
error[E0700]: hidden type for `impl Trait` captures lifetime that does not appear in bounds
  --> src/lib.rs:11:74
   |
11 | pub async fn test_3<'a, 'b>(_a: &'a str, _b: &'b str, _c: &'static str)  {
   |                                                                          ^
   |
note: hidden type `impl Future` captures lifetime smaller than the function body
  --> src/lib.rs:11:74
   |
11 | pub async fn test_3<'a, 'b>(_a: &'a str, _b: &'b str, _c: &'static str)  {
   |
```

Playground link for reference: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4d90427b4a592ccc3b3d119a326cc401

My current rust version:

```
$ rustc --version
rustc 1.56.1 (59eed8a2a 2021-11-01)
```

I came across this issue while trying to add a ring digest algorithm argument to a function that had two reference arguments already. A workaround is pretty easy, as I can wrap the static reference in a struct, pass that in, and use it without issue. I am just curious why this breaks.

Comment: I'd say it is a bug in the compiler, when it tries to deduce the bound lifetime of the returned future. I see no reason why adding a `' static` argument should change the logic.

Comment: I think it's a current limitation of async/await synthax [(see #89056)](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/89056) when you have mulitple lifetimes associated with 'static lifetime and that these lifetimes are unrelated. See [this playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=bfe98c49c51aa22a9d350eddbabb9123) which compiles

Comment: @Jerboas86: I didn't understand a word of your linked PR, but the included [test case](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/89056/files#diff-0505f6c72b1e50469cecea65b393ffce867a8cbaf1b2758d1c7047df8ab5b0b4R14) looks exactly like this question, so I think you are right.

Comment: @Jerboas86 I think you're right. If you want to add an answer with your comment, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

###### The "impl Future" version compiles

```rust
pub fn test_3<'a, 'b>(_a: &'a str, _b: &'b str, _c: &'static str) -> impl Future
{
   async {}
}
```

###### The async version doesn't compile

```rust
pub async fn test_3<'a, 'b>(_a: &'a str, _b: &'b str, _c: &'static str)  {
}
```

The reason why the `impl Future` version compiles is because `_a`, `_b`, and `_c` references are not captured by the future. The compiler is smart enough to remove the references, we can see that with the HIR of the function.

```rust
pub fn test_3<'a, 'b>(_a: &'a str, _b: &'b str, _c: &'static str)
 -> /*impl Trait*/ { #[lang = "from_generator"](|mut _task_context| { }) }
```

You can compare it with the HIR of the async version. In this case, the references are all captured.

```rust
pub async fn test_3<'a, 'b>(a: &'a str, b: &'b str, c: &'static str)
 -> /*impl Trait*/ where
 'a:'b #[lang = "from_generator"](move |mut _task_context|
                                      {
                                          let a = a;
                                          let b = b;
                                          let c = c;
                                          { let _t = { () }; _t }
                                      })
```

in the async version, all of the input lifetimes to the function are captured in the future returned by the async function, like so `impl Future + 'a + 'b + 'static`. In the end, all these lifetimes are unified by the compiler into one lifetime '0. This unification is done by the member constraint algorithm by "least choice" into a set of lifetimes.

for our specific case, we got '0 min(['a, 'b, 'static]). The problem is that there is no obvious minimum in this set since the compiler doesn't know the relationship between 'a and 'b.

If you give this info to the compiler, the async version compiles

```rust
pub async fn test_3<'a, 'b>(a: &'a str, b: &'b str, c: &'static str) 
    where 'a:'b
{
   ()
}
```

Another solution could be to choose 'static in the case of no obvious least choice. It is discussed in this [PR#89056](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/89056)

Comment: Apologies for how long it took me to approve this. I lost track of it. Your answer goes above and beyond. Very clear & understandable description of a difficult topic! Wish I could upvote it twice.

Comment: Thanks. It takes me time to transform my comment into an answer. i hope i get all things right. the subject seems quite moving and complicated.